# How do I aggregate every 5 seconds in bigquery using SQL?

Tags: google-bigquery

I need sql help for BigQuery to find the total quantity every 5 seconds.

Table:

| id | quantity | created_at |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 | 2023-08-09 1:32:23.123456 |
| 2 | 150 | 2023-08-09 1:32:26.123456 |
| 3 | 110 | 2023-08-09 1:32:27.123456 |
| 4 | 10 | 2023-08-09 1:32:28.123456 |
| 5 | 10 | 2023-08-09 1:33:18.123456 |
| 6 | 10 | 2023-08-09 1:33:20.123456 |

Expected SQL output:

| timestamp_interval_5sec | total_quantity |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-08-09 1:32:20 | 100 |
| 2023-08-09 1:32:25 | 270 |
| 2023-08-09 1:33:15 | 10 |
| 2023-08-09 1:33:20 | 10 |

In addition to the timestamp floor function, I was also looking for solutions with "partition by" and "group by"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider below approach (BigQuery Standard SQL)

```
select 
  timestamp_seconds(5 * DIV(unix_seconds(timestamp(created_at)), 5)) as timestamp_interval_5sec,
  sum(quantity) as total_quantity
from your_table
group by timestamp_interval_5sec
order by timestamp_interval_5sec
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Comment: Thanks for posting the results as well. No GPT can replace the super stack overflow community. I fixed the question with the correct output.

Comment: i am sure, SO was "heavily" used to train their model

Answer (score 1):

You may use the **TIMESTAMP_SECONDS** and **TIMESTAMP_ADD** methods to round down the created_at timestamp to the nearest 5-second interval when aggregating data in BigQuery using SQL. Then, to obtain the required result, utilize a mix of PARTITION BY, GROUP BY, and aggregate functions.

```html
WITH intervals_rounded AS (
  SELECT
    TIMESTAMP_SECONDS(5 * (UNIX_SECONDS(created_at) / 5)) AS interval_start,
    SUM(quantity) AS total_quantity
  FROM
    your_table_name
  GROUP BY
    interval_start
)
SELECT
  interval_start,
  total_quantity
FROM
  intervals_rounded
ORDER BY
  interval_start;
```

check this out: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators

Comment: Thanks a lot. Minor correction as TIMESTAMP_SECONDS(INT64).
TIMESTAMP_SECONDS(DIV(UNIX_SECONDS(created_at), 5) * 5) worked.